# Using preg_split on alpha-numeric string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, alphanumeric, preg-split

Consider the string `12345aaa`. I want to use `preg_split()` on it so only the numeric part of it will be returned (i.e. `12345`). How would I write the regex for it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

preg_split is not the function you want, you want [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) as you don't want to split a string into parts, but to retrieve part of it. As I don't know more details, I can only provide a rough example of how to do it.

```
$reg = null;
//match the first set of 1 or more numbers
if ( preg_match('/\d+/', $str, $reg) ){
    $num = $reg[0];
}
```

Comment: No need to wrap `\d+` in parentheses. Use `$reg[0]`. It contains the full match.